# Automate SQL Server 2008 backup and restore on shared hosting with limited permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-restore, windows-server-2012

I have a windows virtual private server (VPS) Windows Server 2012, with SQL Server 2008, on which I have complete access to the `Production` database for my web application. This allows me to use `SQLBackupAndFTP` to backup the database and place it on my mirror hosting, which is a shared hosting with limited privileges (no restore privilege).

I want to automatically restore the mirror server database every night to the copy of the production database.

The mirror server is used as a fall back in case the production server was to ever go, we would could at a minimum restore to last nights production environment.

How can I achieve this given I have limited permissions?

I have no access to the shared hosting via RDP, or SSH etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don’t have full access to SQL Server and the machine that is running it you can’t really initiate a restore command (maybe there are some workarounds but I’m not familiar with any).

What you can do if SQL Server is on a public IP address is setup some kind of replication between two servers so they synchronize automatically. Again, not sure if this is possible w/o full access to machine but you can give it a try.

Final solution would be to use one of the third party comparison and synchronization tools to synchronize databases at a given time. Just find a tool that has command line interface such as [Data Diff from Apex](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx). Another one you can use is Data Compare from [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/) but I’m sure there must be others too.

Note that these tools are not free …

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, Your first 2 suggestions aren't possible without full database access. Using a SQL compare tool means that I would have to manually perform that, when i need it to be done automatically every night